# Map several functions in one routine

Tags: function-construction, automation

I have several functions, let's assume they are:

```
func1[x_]=x;
func2[x_]=3*x-5;
func3[x_]=0.1*x^2;
```

and a lot more like these.

For each and every one of these I want to do the following

```
xvalues = Range[0, 500, 2.5];
points1 = Map[func1, xvalues];
Do[If points1[[[i]] < 0, points1[[i]] = 0, points1[[i]] = points1[[i]], 
 {i, 1,  Length[points1]}]
table1 = Transpose[{xvalues, points1}];
```

Now seeing as I have a lot of these functiones, is there any way to automate this in some kind of routine?

While answering, please be aware that I don't really have any extensive Mathematica knowledge.

Comment: There is some mismatch with braces in your code. Why `points1[[i]] = points1[[i]]`? Maybe you should write a higher order procedure with a function as an argument.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just noticed that! And points1[[i]] = points1[[i]] is there because it's actually points1[[i]] = Re[points1[[i]]] in my code, because some of my functions give out complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
apply[func_] := Module[{}, xvalues = Range[0, 500, 2.5];
    points1 = Map[func1, xvalues];
    Do[If[points1[[i]] < 0, points1[[i]] = 0], {i, 1, Length[points1], 1}];
    table1 = Transpose[{xvalues, points1}]];
```

Now you call the function apply with your desired funcX as an argument

```
apply[func1]
```

Or you can automate this by defining

```
allFuncs = {func1, func2, func3, func4};
```

and then

```
apply/@allFuncs
```

will run them all.

Comment: But then how do I call the table created with the apply function? Now it seems like everytime I call the function, "table1" will be overwritten.

Comment: Make table1 the output of the function. Remove the semicolon from the end of the line with `table1=`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with the return value (and without) and I get an error saying"Do::itform: "Argument points1[[i]]=0 at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator"

Comment: Copy from above. You had an extra right bracket in your Do loop. I fixed it.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I actually found out I missed two curly brackets around the whole if statement, because I also need that little bit with points1[[i]] = points1[[i]] which is points1[[i]] = Re[points1[[i]]] in my code! But I figured it out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

```
f = {# &, 3*# - 5 &, 0.1*#^2 &};
xvalues = Range[0, 500, 2.5];
t1 = Through[f[xvalues]] /. x_ /; x < 0 -> 0;
ListPlot[t1, DataRange -> {0, 500}]
```

[image]

Comment: I would make one change: add `DataRange -> {0, 500}` to `ListPlot`, otherwise, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer I was doing that while you were writing your comment :)

Comment: (:, what no love for doing it in one pass? I should revoke my +1. :D

Comment: But this only plots the values, doesn't make them accessible as a table, which is what I need to export them. I should have maybe added that in the original post, but I need a table for each function in the end.

Comment: @freda42 `t1`holds all your values

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify your code a bit, merging everything into the `Map` statement, and move everything into a function, as follows:

```
process[func_, xvals_] :=
 Block[{points},
  points = Map[ With[{val = func@#}, UnitStep[val] val]&, xvals];
  Transpose[{xvals, points}]
 ]
```

and then for your functions, you can simply run

```
process[func1, Range[0, 500, 2.5]]
```

Or, if you prefer to bury your `xvals` inside your function, just do this, instead:

```
process[func_, xvals_:Range[0, 500, 2.5]] :=
 Block[{points},
  points = Map[ With[{val = func@#}, UnitStep[val] val]&, xvals];
  Transpose[{xvals, points}]
 ]
```